# prevent numbers from automatically converting octal to decimal in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array contains two elements `[0010, 0011];` like this. i need the same two elements in the output also.

```
var a = [0010, 0011];
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    console.log(a[i]); // output is 8, 9 (expected output 0010,0011)
}
```

Comment: Don't put the zeros on the front of the values. That's just basic JavaScript syntax. (Also some other languages.) Or make the values strings, if what they look like is more important than their numeric values.

Comment: no i need solution for this. I know how to do without zeroes

Comment: Then make them strings. There's nothing you can do to tell JavaScript not to interpret a numeric constant the way it thinks it should.

Comment: If you want that exact representation, store strings in the array instead. A number is a number is a number, the only thing that differs is the string representation of them...

Comment: Please give the exact reason of why it is happening like this. I know that to convert into string and work

Comment: The *exact* reason is because that's how JavaScript decimal notation works.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the numbers to strings for display using the `toString` function.

```
console.log(a[i].toString(8)); // displays in base 8 (octal)
```

This way they stay in numeric form in your array, so you can still do math operations on them.

Comment: yes ofcourse this is what my expected output thank you.

Comment: @htoniv you said your "expected output" included the leading zeros, but this won't give you those. If that's OK, then I am happy that you have found your answer :)

Comment: if u know the full answer please post me @Pointy

Answer (score 0):

Use String as javascript interprets numeric constants as octal.

`var a = ["0010", "0011"];
     for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        console.log(a[i]); // expected output 0010,0011
    }`

Comment: I dont want the answer in string i need the reason.